# pdfkit : header containing watermark not repeating

Tags: django, watermark, pdfkit

In my Django project, I need to add watermark on all the pages of the pdf document being generated.
I initially tried with regular css but ended up getting multiple watermarks per page.
To work around it, i created a template only for header and mapped it against a url.

my header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    #watermark
    {   
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
      opacity: 0.5;
        top: 300px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="watermark">
        <img src="/media/images/policy_cancel.png" style="
        width: 650px;
        height: 414px;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

in my urls.py

```
re_path(r'^header/$', views.header),
```

I'm passing this as options in pdfkit as follows :

```
    _options = {
        'cookie': [
            ('csrftoken', options.get('csrftoken','none')),
            ('sessionid', options.get('session_key','none')),
        ],
        'footer-center': 'Page [page] of [topage]',
        'footer-right': DOC_VERSION.get(doctype,''),
        'footer-font-size': '9',
        'header-html': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/b/header/',
    }
```

ISSUE : when pdf is generated, the header is getting printed only on the first page and the footer related configurations have been lost.